# Depth reconstruction from disparity map using stereo camera

Tags: opencv, stereo-3d

I'm working on depth reconstruction from disparity map. I use OpenCV to calibrate my stereo camera, then undistort and rectify the images. I use LibELAS to compute the disparity map.

My question is: According to OpenCV document (https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d53/tutorial_py_depthmap.html), the depth is computed by `depth = Baseline*focal_length/disparity`. But according to middlebury dataset (http://vision.middlebury.edu/stereo/data/scenes2014/), the depth is computed by `depth = baseline * focal_length / (disparity + doffs)`. The "doffs" is "x-difference of principal points, doffs = cx1 - cx0".

What does the "doffs" mean ? How can I get the "doffs" from OpenCV calibration ?

Answer (score 0):

The OpenCV-Calibration gives you the intrinsic matrices for both of your cameras. These are 3x3 Matrices with the following style: (from [doc](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/calib3d/camera_calibration/camera_calibration.html#theory))

```
  fx  0  cx
  0  fy  cy
  0   0   1
```

`cx` and `cy` are the coordiantes of your principle point. From there you can calculate `doffs` as stated by you. With ideal cameras these parameters are the center of the image. But in real cameras they differ in a few pixels.